# Undefined variable $home in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I’m new to using CodeIgniter 4 and I’m encountering an issue. I’m getting an error message ErrorException: Undefined variable $home when trying to pass data from my controller to my view.

Here’s the code I’m using:

Model (`App\Models\indexModel`):

```
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class indexModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = "home";

    protected $allowedFields = [
        'front_name',
        'back_name',
        'jalan',
        'email',
        'telepon',
        'facebook',
        'whatsapp',
        'instagram'
    ];
}
```

Controller (`App\Controllers\Index`):

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Models\indexModel;

class Index extends Controller
{
    public function indexController()
    {
        //model initialize
        $account = new indexModel();

        $data = array(
            'home' => $account->findAll()
        );

        echo view('partial/header', $data);
    }
}
```

View (`partial/header`):

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-center text-lg-right">
    <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center">
        <?php foreach ($home as $key => $account): ?>
            <a class="text-white px-3" href="<?= $account['facebook'] ?>">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="text-white px-3" href="<?= $account['whatsapp'] ?>">
                <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="text-white px-3" href="<?= $account['instagram'] ?>">
                <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
            </a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I’ve checked and it seems like my code is correct, but I’m still getting this error. Can anyone help me understand what’s wrong and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: most likely `$account->findAll()` provokes a 501/no data: could you check with a `print_r($data);die;` just below?

Comment: Array ( [home] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [front_name] => Laundry [back_name] => Q [jalan] => street [email] => email@gmail.com [telepon] => +6286152345[facebook] => https://www.facebook.com// [whatsapp] => wa.me/= [instagram] => https://www.instagram.com/) ) )

Comment: `<?php foreach ($home[0] as $key => $account): ?>` will give you the results of the 1st *home* array. In case you expect only one recordset to be returned, fine, if not you need to add another outer foreach loop to catch recordsets in home[0], home[1], etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```php
'home' => $account->findAll()
```

Use:

```php
'home' => $account->findAll() ?? []
```

Comment: note: the [Null coalescing operator `??`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) was introduced as new feature in PhP 7

Comment: @Vickel Thanks for this reminder. I believe it's all good since [codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4#server-requirements) requires PHP 7.4 or higher to start with.  So this should work nonetheless.

Comment: just wanted to add the note, since someone could try to use `??` with CI-3.x (maybe on a legacy or learning) project, with PhP 5.x